# TightVNC server, running on Windows 10 ignores mouse and keyboard inputs from TightVNC viewer, running on Windows 8.1

Tags: networking, windows-10, mouse, vnc, tightvnc

**The Setup:**

- TightVNC server (v 2.8.8) running on Windows 10, with admin rights.
- TightVNC viewer (v 2.8.8) running on Windows 8.1 with admin rights.
- Firewalls are configured to enable local and shared network connections.
- Server runs in password protection mode and enables mouse inputs.
- Both computers are connected via the local DHCP server (using home wi-fi of the ADSL modem indeed)

**The Status:**

- The viewer successfully connects to the server.
- Client window opens, and shows the host desktop (it's live view).
- Mouse cursor moves.

**The Problem:**

- But all clicks and keyboard inputs are ignored; i.e., no interaction as if it was *View Only* mode, but it isn't.

**Weirdo Stuff**

- At first it was working ok; but then suddenly no more interaction ?
- By suitable means (viewing network activity) I can see that mouse clicks are actually transmitted to the server side computer but somehow ignored by (who?) ?

Any suggestions are appreciated, as I've possibly come to the end of trial and error approach...

Comment: I have had no problem with UltraVNC, connecting to the UVNC server from both Windows UVNC clients and Remmina on Ubuntu, which to me shows the robustness of the server. If you temporarily replace your TVNC server with UVNC, this will help to isolate whether the problem is in the server or the client.

Comment: @AFH  hm thanks, that's a possible solution attack. Indeed, I've previously used Real VNC and even Tight VNC itself successfully, including intra and inter net connections. But just today mouse click processing is gone. I have shut down the other computer for now, so I will try your suggestion and turn you asap is that ok ? (btw: do you mean that UVNC is a better, free, opensource, secure, reliable, robust alternative and I should move onto it instead of TVNC?)

Comment: I recall many years ago using TVNC, but after finding some problems (too long ago to remember) I switched to UVNC. I think I had moved to TVNC from RVNC, but again my recollections are hazy. Having found that UVNC meets my requirements, I have not since had reason to switch again. It's quite possible that other versions of VNC have been improved, so that I would now be happy with them, but having found a satisfactory version I have not needed to investigate them again. UVNC works well for me, but that is as much of a recommendation as I can make, with no implication that it will suit you.

Comment: @AFH oh thanks again. I have no special preference on TVNC other than it being a free app compared to RVNC, indeed RVNC for home use is also free. So I'll give it a try as well and then may be the problem dissappears. I'll let you know the result, thanks again.

Comment: @AFH Hi! Today I tested UVNC, ( uvnc2me ). It works fine but a little *slow*? quite noticeable mouse lag happens. This does not happen with RVNC or TVNC, as they have control over JPEG comression quality to improve desktop streaming. I could ot find that control with uvnc2me ? Did I downloaded the correct tool? Or should I use another variant as they seem to have 4 different variants? Which one do you suggest for the easiest configure, yet still having enough control for the user at home nwtwork ?

Comment: It is some time since I set up my UVNC server configuration. My concern was for optimum quality, but when I look at the current configuration options, I cannot see options for colour depth or compression depth. I mostly use it on my local intranet, and I have not noticed adverse performance here. I prefer TeamViewer when I'm working remotely, and this gives good performance and it's free for non-commercial use. Unfortunately, I can't do a side-by-side test for remote working while I'm at home. I haven't updated for some time: I am running UltraVNC 1.2.1.0 (not the 2me version).

Comment: I've just noticed that the quality controls are in the client, not the server.

Comment: @AFH hmm. I think the simplicity of *uvnc2me* disables any advanced controls; it has *fps* control but that's not enough. I will also test other uvnc suits and see their configurability. btw I shut down the other (server) computer again and will test it later and let you know th result. Thanks for your time...

Comment: @AFH I haven't done any testing since then. Probably I just gave up using all remote things...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checked and found that "View Only (inputs ignored) was selected under the "Restrictions" in the "Connection Options" on the VIEWER side console. Deselected it, all OK.

Comment: Unable to locate the 'Connection Option'. Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

When you press `Ctrl` or `Alt` key while in the tightvnc viewer, the click and typing doesn't work. You can resume this by pressing the `Ctrl` and `Alt` key again while the window of vnc viewer is active. You can see the `Ctrl` and `Alt` icons being enabled/disabled in the viewer by pressing those keys.

Sometimes when you switch to different windows using `Alt+Tab` keys, the `Alt` key is enabled in vnc viewer and when you come back to the vnc viewer you will not be able to click and type. Simply press the `Alt` key again and voila you will be able to click and type again.

If there is some way to disable this functionality that would be really appreciated.